# Using alias with subqueries

Tags: sql, count, integer-division

I've got a problem with one of my SQL requests, which is made with subqueries.

I'm trying to divide the results of two `COUNT(*)` requests:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book) nb_books,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author) nb_authors,
       nb_books / nb_authors
```

(my request is much more complex and I simplified it for the example)

But MySQL keeps telling `Unknown column nb_books in field list`. Isn't there any way to
 make this request to work?

Thanks for your answers.

(PS: my request is generated from DQL by Doctrine, so it may be more difficult to customize it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two choices :

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book)  as nb_books ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author) as nb_authors,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book) /  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author)
```

Or

```
SELECT nb_books, nb_authors, nb_books/nb_authors
FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book) nb_books,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author) nb_authors
)
```

I prefer the second way. You may have to put a condition if nb_authors could be equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks about the answer. It worked with my simple example but unfortunately my request is really complicated and I can't get it to work with Doctrine. Never mind.